# Can we use be without modal?

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs

We use this sentence 'he should be here'. Can we say he be here? Without modal?

Comment: No, because "he be here" has no meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the suggested interpretation. A possible version - with the *subjunctive* form of the verb 'to be':

> It is necessary that he be here, be he dead or alive.

Comment: That is possible, but is a rather unusual form, and I think a somewhat old-fashioned usage.